# JavaFX bind a controller variable to a component property

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, javafx-2, fxml

Say I have a controller with

```
@FXML private ObservableList<String> myStrings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Is it possible to write any FXML which will wire up a ListView with `myStrings` as its items?

My first try was:

```
<ListView>
    <items fx:id="myStrings"/>
</ListView>
```

But this complains that `fx:id` is not valid in that position. I also tried

```
<ListView items="${controller.myStrings}"/>
```

...but it couldn't resolve that value.

### Please do not post this solution:

```
<ListView fx:id="myStringsListView"/>

// In controller
@FXML private ListView<String> myStringsListView;
@FXML public void initialize() {
    myStringsListView.setItems(myStrings);
}
```

This is what I am doing now but the amount of indirection and boilerplate here hurts me.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2307758

Comment: To do this in `FXML` you need to have a determined set of values. If you are going to make changes to the `ListView`, it's best to use code instead of `FXML` to handle the `ListView`.

Comment: This line of code is wrong: `@FXML private ObservableList<String> myStrings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, what is wrong with that line of code specifically...?? Seems to work fine.

Also I am not interested in changing anything on the ListVIew aside from its items. I don't want a ListView instance in my controller if I can help it. There's no reason for it, beyond calling `setItems()`

Comment: Normally, when you define something in `FXML`, you never set that something `=` equal to something. So with that in mind, you defined `myStrings` in `FXML`. Then you overwrite the `FXML`'s  declaration with `myStrings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`. Also, I have dealt with `ListView ` a lot and I have never seen an example that starts an `ObservableList` with `@FXML`.

Comment: The `@FXML` annotation on a *field* in a controller indicates that the field is initialized by the `FXMLLoader`; consequently it's always an error to also initialize it in code: either the annotation is redundant or the initialization is redundant. The `${x.y}` syntax in FXML resolves to a *property* (in the usual JavaBeans sense) called `y` belonging to some member `x` of the FXML namespace. The FXML namespace is populated with elements with `fx:id` attributes, plus some privileged objects such as the `controller`, `resources`, and `location`.

Comment: Consequently, `${controller.myStrings}` works if you have a JavaBeans-style property called `myStrings`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ListViewController">
    <center>
        <ListView items="${controller.myStrings}" />
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

with the following controller (the main difference, I think, being that you either didn't define an accessor method for the list, or named it incorrectly):

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ListViewController {

    private final ObservableList<String> myStrings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ListViewController() {
        myStrings.addAll("One", "Two", "Three");
    }

    public ObservableList<String> getMyStrings() {
        return myStrings ;
    }
}
```

This quick test:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewItemsFromControllerTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ListViewItemsFromController.fxml"))));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

produces

[image]